# Key considerations when applying for a Ph.D. abroad

Tags: phd, career-path, academic-life, international-students

I'm in the process of applying for a Ph.D. in a foreign country, and I'm trying to determine the most crucial factors to consider.

How should I prioritize aspects like the reputation or expertise of the professor, the city's living conditions, the country's academic environment, and the specific field of study? I'm seeking insights or experiences to guide me in making a well-informed decision.

Comment: Will you be going alone or taking your family?

Comment: I'll be alone. @Buffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly think that the most important factor to consider when applying for a Ph.D. abroad is being wanted or needed by the program and your potential supervisor. If you do your part, this alignment will lead to fruitful collaboration, publications, grants, etc. It's crucial to find a program where you're not just another student as is usually the case in a prestigious university but one where you're genuinely needed. A program that values you will typically assist with practical issues like visa processes, migration challenges, and housing. To me, this is the primary factor for consideration.

On a secondary note, the direction of the research is also vital. It's essential to find a place where your research interests align with the program, but more importantly, where your strengths and potential new contributions to the program are recognized/needed. The goal is to avoid internal competition and to carve out your little niche in a research field.